# Android : illegaljavaexception Could not execute the method for activity

Tags: android

I'm trying using intent to add class to an application. I have made SecondAcitivity class and modified the manifest file as well. My application is running i.e. First activity Containing the button works well, but onclick on button the error comes and it does not displays a second activity.

This is my MainActivity.java file

```
package com.intent.usingintent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        startActivity(new Intent("com.intent.SecondActivity"));
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.intent.usingintent"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.intent.usingintent.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="com.intent.SecondActivity"
        android:label="SecondActivity" >
    </activity>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name=".SecondActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    </intent-filter>
</application>

</manifest>
```

ERROR LOG

```
07-09 13:57:45.922: W/dalvikvm(20185): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d8e2a0)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3699)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3694)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    ... 11 more
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.intent.SecondActivity }
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1580)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1431)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3446)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3407)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3617)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3585)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    at com.intent.usingintent.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:17)
07-09 13:57:45.932: E/AndroidRuntime(20185):    ... 14 more
07-09 13:57:57.072: I/Process(20185): Sending signal. PID: 20185 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

In your App, your second activity in `com.intent.usingintent`  package.And your intent action is `com.intent.SecondActivity`,and  write `<intent-filter>` inside `<activity>` tag.

So in manifest file,Change

```
  <activity 
        android:name="com.intent.SecondActivity"
        android:label="SecondActivity" >
    </activity>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name=".SecondActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    </intent-filter>
```

to

```
 <activity 
        android:name="com.intent.usingintent.SecondActivity"
        android:label="SecondActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.intent.SecondActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced `IntentFilter` for the `SecondActivity` in the manifest. Put it insude `<activity></activity>`

Though you do no treally need that you can simply do `startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));`

Comment: @user3819121 : also change `<action android:name=".SecondActivity" />` to `<action android:name="com.intent.SecondActivity" />`

Comment: hey, done activity name was wrong in the second part

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest file instead of this

```
<activity 
        android:name="com.intent.SecondActivity"
        android:label="SecondActivity" >
    </activity>
```

replace with

```
<activity 
        android:name="com.intent.usingintent.SecondActivity"
        android:label="SecondActivity" >
    </activity>
```

and even in your  java class also

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.intent.SecondActivity"));
```

replace this with

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.intent.usingintent.SecondActivity"));
```

Comment: you are always welcome.....try to upvote the answer with right symbol to my answer you can find below to down arrow...

Answer (score 0):

change in manifest file

```
       <activity
        android:name="com.intent.usingintent.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="SecondActivity"></activity>
```

change in click event

```
    Intent n=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);

                startActivity(n);
```